# How to Manually Install IvyDE in MyEclipse?

Tags: eclipse, myeclipse, ivyde

I tried to install IvyDE in MyEclipse 10 through Eclipse Marketplace. After installation is done, it shows that IvyDE is installed but I don't see any Ivy feature is available, neither in Preferences. So I have to install it manually? I have visited Apache official website to download some files and see what I can do follow up with the instructions and it doesn't seem working fine. Probably I did it wrongly. How exactly to do it in correct way?

[image]

[image]

Comment: MyEclipse 10 is based on eclipse 3.7. Maybe the latest IvyDE doesn't work with such an old release. Try to get a release compatible with eclipse 3.7 or upgrade to a supported release of MyEclipse (I think release 10 is 6 releases old, around 2011-2012).

Comment: @TonyWeddle https://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/history/latest-milestone/compatibility.html `"Apache IvyDE has been maintained to be compatible with Eclipse 3.4 to 3.7, and 4.2."` I've checked the compatibility of latest IvyDE 2.2 on Apache's website and it seem should works fine with MyEclipse 10 (Eclipse 3.7).

Comment: OK. Well, you might try to ask on the Apache IVY mailing list, though you could try starting with the `-clean` option added to the start of myeclipse.ini file (remove it after one launch as it slows the start). Check in the error log for any errors related to IvyDE.

Comment: Tried out a restart with `-clean` option included in `myeclipse.ini`. Not helpful as well. Ivy still not shows up. I left a message in mailing list too, not sure how long it would takes...